# mysql - add id in new column based on composite key

Tags: mysql

I have a table where for the same combination of 3 columns a new column with a new id needs to be generated. E.G:

```
col1   col2   col3   newcol

1      1      2      newid1
1      1      2      newid1
1      2      2      newid2
```

Can someone point me to a solution or give me a hint how to achieve this? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If new values could be sequential then:

```
SELECT *,CONCAT('newid', DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col1,col2,col3)) AS newcol
FROM tab
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e005a740c5b7d16ad2755525ed925cf)**